# DigialOcean Droplet clone of a wordPress website - DNS not resolving

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I have a website **mywebsite1.com** runing **wordpress** and hosted on digitalOcean droplet using **LEMP** (Nginx/php/mysql) on Ubunto server, am trying to duplicate the same site and use a new DNS **mywebsite2.com** to point to the new droplet IP, the problem is that the new DNS doesn't load and try to connect to the server then stop loading, here what I got
on fireFox :

```
Unable to connect
```

on chrome :

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I am a Linux beginner, so for sure there's something missing .. here what I did step by step :

- On my DNS provider I added **A** type **mywebsite2.com** to point to my new Droplet IP.
- CNAME **www.mywebsite2.com** to point to  **mywebsite2.com**
- Updated my databasedump.sql with the new domain **mywebsite2.com**
- Updated my config.php file (Wordpress)
- Renamed my website directory :

> /home/html/mywebsite1.com to /home/html/mywebsite2.com

```
ls -l
```

[image]

- Go to :

> /etc/nginx/sites-available and renamed mywebsite1.com to mywebsite2.com and updated all the file

- Delete the old symlink and create a new one for the new DNS, using this cmd :

> sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mywebsite2.com
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mywebsite2.com

- Restart nginx ..

**Note :** I have an SSL certificate (Wildcard) that is working on mywebsite1.com, but recently bought a new one for mywebsite2.com and left the same config and put the new certification files (public & private)

**Note 2 :** Runing ping to mywebsite2.com is working and whois (cmd) give me the right DNS provider.

What am I missing please? Any suggestion is very welcome am trying to figure out what is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: heh, probably would be faster if you give an actual domain for people to see what's up?

Comment: Okay no problem, here the link : http://goo.gl/2iIZkM

Comment: mychippewasublease.com / 162.243.74.152 doesn't have anything running on its http or https ports; unless blocked by the firewall, looks like nginx might not be running on your box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless blocked by a firewall, it looks like your nginx is not presently running:

```
% host ██████████████████.com
██████████████████.com has address 162.243.74.152
...

% telnet 162.243.74.152 80
Trying 162.243.74.152...
telnet: connect to address 162.243.74.152: Connection refused

% telnet 162.243.74.152 443
Trying 162.243.74.152...
telnet: connect to address 162.243.74.152: Connection refused

% telnet 162.243.74.152 ssh
Trying 162.243.74.152...
Connected to 162.243.74.152.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.2
```

You can determine whether or not it's running by running one of the following: `ps aux | fgrep nginx`, which should return at least 3 different lines (likely at least 4), and `pgrep nginx`, which should return at least 3 numbers.

Subsequently, I would look into the global [`error_log`](http://nginx.org/r/error_log) to see why nginx is not starting up when you start it (configuration issues would be reported in the global one, not the local one to the site specified within site's configuration).

Comment: Sorry for taking too long to reply .. first I would like to thank you for your answer! in fact your analysis was true, I run fgrep nginx and I got about 5 lines (which is okay ?) the second nginx pgrep gave me 5 numbers too .. so my nignx was runing ... I checked my error_log and I didn't find anything strange ... so following your instructions my nginx was firewalled ! I tried with nmap and just figure out that I have port 80 & 443 closed ! after some research I figure out that the problem was nothing but the symlink not generated correctly ..

Comment: so I just deleted my site under sites-enabled and run this cmd :
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com

I just accepted your answer ! thanks again, between could you please edit your answer and just hide my Domain name .. :)

Comment: @LMS, glad it worked out!  I've edited the answer to not mention your domain name.  So, what was it in the end -- a firewall issue, or an nginx configuration one?  Normally, if nginx is running, it'll be listening on port 80, or did you somehow managed to run it without a single site being configured? :-)